# why won't my jframe appear?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to display a simple jframe that I will eventually put a canvas in to render 3d objects. Last year I built two GUI programs that used jframe's and I've looked at those and they work fine, but I can't figure out why nothing happens when I run the program. This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Hello3d extends JFrame
{
    JFrame frame;
    JLabel label;

    public Hello3d()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("This is a jframe, YAAAYYYY!!!!");
        frame.setSize( 600, 400 );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        frame.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        label = new JLabel("This is where i put somthing 3d");
        frame.add( label );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Hello3d();
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me. Do you have any exception massage?

Comment: what command are you using to run the program? Are you using an IDE, or command line?

Comment: no problems compiling, and im using jcreator 4.5. also im on windows 8 and on the jcreator website it says 4.5 is only for XP and vista but i used it on windows 7 fine. not sure if this has to do with the problem but some additional info

Comment: @MatthewBuchanan: You failed to start the `Swing GUI` on the `Event Dispatcher Thread - EDT`. Please have a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), for more detail :-) YOu simply creating a new instance of `JFrame`, when the class is actually extending from `JFrame` itself, which means, the class `Hello3d` is actually a `JFrame` in itself. Not related, but why setting Layout for `JFrame`, when `BorderLayout` is actually the default layout of the `JFrame`

Comment: @nIcEcOw im confused by the initail threads link can u explain to me what i need to do there. also i stoped extending Hello3d as a jframe so now im just trying to make "frame" appear, it still compiles but nothing happens.

Comment: @MatthewBuchanan: I have added a simple example, for you to look at, as to what you need to change in the main method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, see if this is working. Please, do watch the main method, since, `Swing GUI` or any `GUI` for that matter, must run in it's own thread, but not `main`. Moreover, instead of setting sizes manually, consider calling `frame.pack()`, this will create a `JFrame` after calculating sizes of the components, contained with this container, in a good sense.

Try to use `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` over, `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, since, the latter is very much similar to using `System.exit(0)`, which simply kills the application, though the former, will graciously wait for all daemon threads to stop, before actually JVM shuts down.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloFrame {
    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello Frame Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(
            "This is where I put something 3D", JLabel.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(label);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new HelloFrame().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't solve the problem, im starting to think theres something wrong with my IDE because it still displays nothing :(. or somthing wrong with my project.

Comment: @MatthewBuchanan: Try running on command prompt/terminal, might be that will give, some idea. Or check `Error Log` of the IDE, there must be something hidden on that window, that might be slipping you.

Comment: i dont know how but i got it to work thank you very much for your help wether it matter or not i learned in the process :).